# Events/Interrupts in Serial Communication

Tags: events, serial-port

I want to read and write from serial using events/interrupts.
Currently, I have it in a while loop and it continuously reads and writes through the serial.  I want it to only read when something comes from the serial port.  How do I implement this in C++?

This is my current code:

```
    while(true)
    {
        //read
        if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
        //error occurred. Report to user.
        }

        //write
        if(!WriteFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
        //error occurred. Report to user.
        }


        //print what you are reading
        printf("%s\n", szBuff);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `select` statement, which will check the read and write buffers without blocking and return their status, so you only need to read when you know the port has data, or write when you know there's room in the output buffer.

The third example at http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=2933 and the associated comments may be helpful.

**Edit:** The man page for select has a simpler and more complete example near the end.  You can find it at http://linux.die.net/man/2/select if `man 2 select` doesn't work on your system.

**Note:** Mastering `select()` will allow you to work with both serial ports and sockets; it's at the heart of many network clients and servers.

Comment: Can I see an example of the select statement being used or a link to an example? I couldn't find it on google.

Comment: I came across two, added above.  I found the man page to be clearer and more concise.  The developerweb link is more socket-oriented but has some Q&A that may help.

Comment: select() only works with POSIX file descriptors (integers), NOT Windows HANDLEs.

Comment: While select can solve the "reading without blocking", it doesn't answer how to "read and write from serial using events/interrupts"

Comment: Curious that an answer that was accepted **14 years ago** because it addressed the salient issue to the OP's satisfaction suddenly merits a criticism from someone who's answered 6 questions in 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows environment the more native approach would be to use [asynchronous I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683(VS.85).aspx).  In this mode you still use calls to ReadFile and WriteFile, but instead of blocking you pass in a callback function that will be invoked when the operation completes.

It is fairly tricky to get all the details right though.

Comment: The trouble with asynch Serial I/O is that the first byte you get is going to trigger your data-read event, after which you have to somehow figure out when you're done getting new data.  I think I'm going to ask a question about that, since there doesn't seem to be a good answer yet

Comment: We typically either (1) read until the buffer is empty, assuming there *is* a buffer, or (2) stay in the read loop until an appropriate timeout occurs.  "Appropriate" is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of an [article](http://www.ewoodruff.us/CUJArticle/CUJArticle.html) that was published in the c/C++ users journal a few years ago.  It goes into detail on the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

here a code that read serial incomming data using interruption on windows
you can see the time elapsed during the waiting interruption time

`int pollComport(int comport_number, LPBYTE buffer, int size)
{
    BYTE Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    DWORD      dwCommModemStatus;
    int n;

    double TimeA,TimeB;
    // Specify a set of events to be monitored for the port.
    SetCommMask (m_comPortHandle[comport_number], EV_RXCHAR );

    while (m_comPortHandle[comport_number] != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        // Wait for an event to occur for the port.
        TimeA = clock();
        WaitCommEvent (m_comPortHandle[comport_number], &dwCommModemStatus, 0);
        TimeB = clock();
        if(TimeB-TimeA>0)
        cout <<"              ok            "<<TimeB-TimeA<<endl;

        // Re-specify the set of events to be monitored for the port.
        SetCommMask (m_comPortHandle[comport_number], EV_RXCHAR);

        if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR) 
        {
            // Loop for waiting for the data.
            do 
            {
               ReadFile(m_comPortHandle[comport_number], buffer, size, (LPDWORD)((void *)&n), NULL);

              // Display the data read.
              if (n>0)
                  cout << buffer <<endl;
            } while (n > 0);
        }
      return(0);
    }
}`